# Modal bottomsheet vs persistance bottomsheet performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, bottom-sheet

i have used bottom sheet before but never deep dive into it. I know there are 2 type of bottom sheet: persistent bottom sheet which we can included it in our screen's content and modal bottom sheet which work like a menu or dialog. Can someone explain to me how each type works and their performance?

Sorry for bad English. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a good article with code and images https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/